# can sparkjava routes contain spaces?

Tags: spark-java

I'm porting a jetty server API that has some routes containing spaces to the sparkjava framework. But the sparkjava server always returns "404 Not found" regardless of how I escape or quote the url that contains the space.

Simplest code, based on the sparkjava HelloWorld:

```
import static spark.Spark.*;

public class Hi {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        get("/hello", (req, res) -> "Hello World");
        get("/hi there", (req, res) -> "Hi There World");
    }
}
```

I've also tried using a redirect, like this:

```
import static spark.Spark.*;

public class Hi {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        get("/hello", (req, res) -> "Hello World");
        get("/hi_there", (req, res) -> "Hi There World");
        // have tried with and without a get("/hi there", ...) here also
        redirect.get("/hi there", "/hi_there");
    }
}
```

Which still just gives the 404.
I've tried with curl, like

```
curl 'localhost:4567/hi there' (curl itself doesn't like this bare space)
curl 'localhost:4567/hi+there'
curl 'localhost:4567/hi%20there'
```

And I've used those same urls directly in the browser with the same 404. I can't see any special handling or ignoring of spaces in the sparkjava code or docs. Maybe spaces in urls are frowned upon, but I don't want our current users to have to change the urls they're using.

So is there a way to have sparkjava handle routes containing spaces?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like sparkjava does a very literal string match when looking up the route, no urlencoding or escaping of special characters. So since curl could use '+' or '%20' for the spaces, and a browser probably uses '%20', then routes for each of those need to be added.

```
import static spark.Spark.*;

public class Hi {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        get("/hello", (req, res) -> "Hello World");
        get("/hi there", (req, res) -> "Hi There World 1");
        get("/hi+there", (req, res) -> "Hi There World 2");
        get("/hi%20there", (req, res) -> "Hi There World 3");
    }
}
```

Would be happy to learn that there's a different or better way, but this works for me now. So `curl 'localhost:4567/hi+there'` now returns `Hi There World 2` as expected.